# Batch files - why does a funny ASCII character appear when redirecting output of tree command to a file?

Tags: batch-file, io-redirection, extended-ascii

The following code:

```
if "%DispMode%"=="tree" (
 tree >temp
 findstr /b /v /c:"F" temp >>temp2
 del temp >nul
 findstr /b /v /c:"V" temp2 >>temp
 del temp2 >nul
 findstr /b /v /c:"A" temp >>temp2
 del temp >nul
 type temp2
 del temp2 >nul
)
```

...for some reason outputs a funny ASCII character at the beginning of the line of each non-root folder and in other places too.  The character looks like a superscript, underlined `a`.  I'm hoping someone can explain why this is happening?

I was able to produce this problem even by just typing `tree >tempfile` at the Win11 command prompt and then `type tempfile`, so I don't think this has anything to do with the block of code, the `findstr` commands, or whatever.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems just one line `if "%DispMode%"=="tree" tree | findstr /bv "F V A"` would do the same job without temporary files.

Comment: What about ```@tree | more +3 >tempfile.txt```, and if required ```@type tempfile.txt```?

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I've used the pipe a lot in the past for |more, but I haven't used it very much outside of that context, so this didn't occur to me.   Compo, I didn't know about the more +n option.  Pretty cool, although that doesn't work for me in this context since I'm not going to want to pause every screenful.

Comment: When you use `more` in the context I used it above, @fortissimo, there is no `pause` mechanism. Did you try the same command I offered?

Comment: Ah yes of course, not sure what I was thinking since there is no `more` mechanism when using `type`.  Still though, Stephan's solution doesn't require the use of any temporary files written to the hard disk, so I went with that one.

Comment: @fortissimo, your question does not ask about omitting a text file though. In fact the title alone is explicit in that the problem is when outputting the result to a file. You are free to change your mind about how you are going about the task, but the question you wrote is what we're here to answer. IMO the commented methodolgy I offered most closely does that, in that both the console output, and text file output does not show a strange character, and it has the added benefit of working with any end user language, _(as you do not need to exclude language dependent line first characters)_.

Comment: @Compo If the objective is to just answer the exact question asked, OJBakker answered the question most directly, which is why I marked his answer as the solution.  Your solution answers the question too.  And Stephan's solution answers the question and also carries the bonus of three less uses of the hard drive (no writing, no reading, and no deleting).  So I combined Stephan's solution with the answer below, and I'm happy and appreciative of all the help everyone has offered.  I'm the only end user of the system I'm building, so working with any language is not a factor for me.

Comment: That is correct, hence the reason mine is not in the answer area. However you specifically stated, please do read it back, that @Stephan offered a better **solution**, which did not require temp files. Stephan did not offer a solution, they showed you that you could have excluded lines with your three beginnning characters in a single `findstr.exe` instance instead of three. That does not attempt in any way to fix your reported issue, whereas my example excludes those lines, and the character issue in a single piped instance to a different built-in executable.

Comment: Ok got it.  I will try to use more precise language next time.  I should have said "improvement" instead of "solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended ascii-characters used by tree are causing your weird characters.
Different character sets show different characters for these extended characters.
Use `Tree /A` to circumvent this problem.